# Get worst predicted classes of multiclass classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am working on a multiclass classificiation problem, where I have a lot of different classes (50+).

The problem is, that I want to highlight the worst predicted classes (e.g. in confusion matrix or whatever), to make some further adjustements in my classifier.

My prediction and test data is saved in a list (small example from sklearn):

```
y_true = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2]
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2]])
```

How can i get the class 1 in this example from the matrix? There the prediction is complete wrong. Is there a way to sort the classes based on their true positive predictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [classifiction_report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) from scikit-learn, which will return a dictionary, with precision, recall and F-score. Then you can print the dictionary in a sorted manner so you can see the worst predicted class easily.

```
#prints classification_report     
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred)

#returns a dict, which you can easily sort by prediction
report = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, output_dict=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple function for this:

```
def print_class_accuracies(confusion_matrix):
    # get the number of occurrences for each class
    counts = {cl: y_true.count(cl) for cl in set(y_true)}
    # extract the diagonal values (true positives)
    tps = dict(enumerate(conf.diagonal()))
    # Get the accuracy for each class, preventing ZeroDivisionErrors
    pred_accuracy = {cl: tps[cl]/counts.get(cl, 1) for cl in tps}
    # Get a ranking, worst accuracies are first/lowest
    ranking = sorted([(acc,cl) for cl, acc in pred_accuracy.items()])
    # Pretty print it
    for acc, cl in ranking:
        print(f"Class {cl}: accuracy: {acc:.2f}")
```